# Prove that a set is Bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functions

In the process of constructing a proof, I obtain the following set. Let C be the set of continuous and nondecreasing functions defined on $[0,1]$. Let the set $B$ be given as follows:

$$
B=\{b_i\in[0,1]: b_i=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|h_i(t)|,\,h_i \in C\}
$$

My question is whether the set $B$ is bounded. In particular, si $B$ bounded above? I don't know how to approach this question so any help/suggestion/comment on how to proceed is really appreciated it!

Comment: It seems that $B$ is bounded above by 1 as it is a subset of $[0,1]$. A set $S$ is bounded above if there exists a $k$ such that $s \leq k$ for all $s \in S$. Therefore, 1 seems to work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your definition, $B$ is clearly a subset of $[0, 1]$. Every element $b \in B$ must also be in $[0, 1]$. $[0, 1]$ is bounded. Therefore, $B$ is also bounded.

If, on the other hand, you don't restrict the elements of $B$ to $[0, 1]$:

$$
B = \{b \in \mathbb{R} : b = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \left|h(t)\right|, \, h \in C\}
$$

Then $B$ is not bounded. No matter what $M \in \mathbb{R}$ you choose, you can construct the following function which belongs to $C$:
$$
f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R} \\
f(t) = t + |M|
$$

$f$ is continuous and non-decreasing. However:
$$
\sup_{t \in [0,1]} \left|f(t)\right| = |M| + 1 > M
$$

Comment: Then, according to Ayman's answer, the set of continuous and nondecreasing functions defined on $[0,1]$ is unbounded, isn't it?

Comment: @Cristian - Every continuous function on a closed interval must be bounded. However, the set of upper bounds for those functions is not bounded.

Comment: Yup..but I was wondering if there exists a bound on the set of continuous and nondecreasing functions...that is, if there is a number $B$ such that $|f(x)|\leq B$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ and all $f$ continuous and nondecreasing. According to your pretty nice answer above, it seems that the answer to my question is no, there is no such $B$...

Comment: @Cristian - Indeed. There is no such $B$.

Comment: Thanks for your help @ayman!

Comment: @Cristian You're welcome!